# Форматирование кода в комментарии не соответствует справке

Tags: дефект, предложение, справка, комментарии

Согласно [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), в комментариях поддерживается

> встраиваемый код в одиночных кавычках

Увы, на практике используется не одинарная кавычка ('), а обратная кавычка (`). Итог - невозможность нормального оформления комментария, содержащего фрагменты MySQL-кода, где бэктики используются для обрамления имён.

Возможные варианты:

1. Оставить обратную кавычку, поправить текст справки;
2. Заменить обратную кавычку на одинарную кавычку;
3. Использовать иное обрамление для форматирования кода, поправить текст справки.

Поскольку одинарные кавычки тоже используются во многих диалектах кода, наиболее разумным видится вариант 3. А в качестве обрамления кода я бы предложил удвоенную обратную кавычку (так же, как удвоенная звёздочка для полужирного шрифта) - по-моему, такое сочетание нигде не используется в качестве служебного или структурного, а если попадётся в литерале - вот это как раз можно и пережить.

Comment: Что в забыл `SQL` в комментах?

Comment: ``Tuple`2`` всё работает, насколько я вижу.

Comment: @Other Вы хотите сказать, что любой текст, где по смыслу нужно привести фрагмент SQL-кода (не весь запрос, а только маленький его кусочек), нужно оформлять как ответ? Позвольте не согласиться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть два способа использовать `` ` `` во внутристрочном коде:

```
``пример ` пример``
`пример \` пример`
```

Ошибку в справке исправим в ближайшее время.

---

Использовать что-то кроме обратных кавычек для обрамления кода не получится:

1. Это часть спецификации Markdown.
2. Пользователи Stack Exchange уже привыкли.

Comment: ``пример ` пример`` 
`пример \` пример`

Comment: Спасибо. Правда, у меня почему-то правильно отрабатывает только второй способ - квотирование бэкслэшем, но это уже неважно.